# Keras RNN design for time series prediction

Tags: keras

I'm working on a Machine Learning project on time series prediction, using Keras library to create the RNN. I'm getting good results but I'm having some trouble to decide on the design of the layers; I'm approaching the issue by trial and error, and I can't seem to find any guidelines online as to how to select the number of layers and neurons on each one. How should I go about this?

My data has 14 variables with 510 days each, and I'm using 80% for training (from which 20% goes to validation) and the rest for testing.
I'm reshaping the net's input as (510, 1, 14), and I've done several simulation taking windows of values backwards, so the shape ends up (510, 1, 14*window_days). I can't understand if setting 1 as the timestep and adding the values of previous timesteps as variables is the correct way or if I should reshape the input.

This is the model I'm using:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 4, dropout=0, 
               input_shape=(1, train_X.shape[2]), 
               return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(LSTM(units = 1))
model.add(Dense(units = train_Y.shape[1], activation = 'linear'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

history = model.fit(train_X, train_Y, 
                    epochs=400, batch_size=150,
                    validation_split=0.2,shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently not predicting based on time series. You number of *timesteps* is 1, this is set by `input_shape=(1, train_x.shape[2])`. So the LSTM even if you have a window, you are just looking at one iteration of the LSTM. This is similar to flattening the timesteps and using a dense layer.

Instead, keep your data as (510, 14) which is 510 days and 14 features per day. Now you can use a [TimeseriesGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/#timeseriesgenerator) to window over the sequence and produce (samples, window_size, 14). Now, the LSTM will actually process the sequence of 14 inputs over the window size.